# Use of PrimeQ in Solve

Tags: equation-solving, prime-numbers

I fail to use `PrimeQ` in `Solve`. Simple example:

```
Solve[PrimeQ[p] && 0 < p < 5, p, Integers]
```

yields `{}` rather than `{{p -> 2}, {p -> 3}}`.

How can this be fixed (for more complex problems)?

---

There's the same issue with `OddQ`rather than `PrimeQ`, but I know workarounds, like

```
Solve[p == 2 k + 1 && 0 < p < 5, {p, k}, Integers]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PrimeQ` is a predicate that only ever evaluates to `True` or `False`. It does not indicate that $p$ should be a prime number. It shares this behavior with all other `*Q` predicates, like `OddQ`.

Instead, you could use either one of the following options:

```
Solve[{0 < p < 5, p ∈ Primes}, p]
Solve[0 < p < 5, p, Primes]

(* Out: {{p -> 2}, {p -> 3}} *)
```

To see what is happening in your attempt, take a look at the `Trace` results:

```
Solve[{PrimeQ[p], 0 < p < 5}, p] // Trace
```

[image: trace output showing that primeq[p] is immediately evaluated to false]

As you can see, `PrimeQ[p]` is immediately evaluated to `False` because `p` is not manifestly a prime number. This behavior is also indicated in the [documentation of `PrimeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimeQ.html).

Comment: `p ∈ Primes` or `Element[p, Primes]` rather than `PrimeQ[p]`, that's great!